# JIRA: How to automate sub-tasks movement

Tags: jira

I have stories with subtasks (we make heavy use of them) I would like

1) That when all sub-tasks of a story are done, the story moves alone to done

2) That when a story is moved (for instance) from "Idea" to "Backlog", or from "Backlog" to "Ready", all its sub-tasks move with him. So in coders language, that when a Story is moved by dragging the story, all related sub-tasks status get's overridden by the new story status.

The boards structure guarantees no problems since the PO has only one colum for all development status (dev, review, etc) and development scrum board has only status those dev, review, etc colums so .. Everything should be Ok

Furthermore the PO board is only viewing stories and using Epics as swimlanes so he cannot see the sub-tasks moving. And the developers board is only showing sub-tasks using stories as swimlines.

So developers cannot move the stories to Done.. only the sub-tasks.

Comment: are you use cloud or standalone? scriptrunner plugin?

Comment: im using server version (running in our machines) and no paid plugin. I can install free plugins

Comment: From my experience automate movement is not possible. When all subtasks are done we have to explicitly move main task to done.You may create main task also resource specific and assign to developer so that the developers can move main task as well to completed.

Comment: Jira Data Center 9.0 comes with Automatiion for Jira

Answer (score 0):

Can do all this through validators on workflow transitions

Comment: for "when all sub-tasks of a story are done, the story moves along to done", can use Jira ScriptRunner and make it listen for all subtask transitions